# PHP webscoket личные сообщения

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

Есть товары на сайте, у каждого своё айди, свой продавец.
Как сделать ЛС ,чтобы пользователь мог нажать на кнопку "написать продавцу" - создать новый чат и писать там продавцу сообщения, а продавец отвечать.

Ну те простой ДИАЛОГ.

---

> **1.** Сообщения должны отправляться только между продавец<--->покупатель и никому больше.
>
> **2.** Одному продавцу может написать несколько разных покупателей
>
> **3.** У одного продавца может быть несколько товаров на продажу
>
> **4.** Сделать уведомления

---

Я устанавливал библиотеку `RATCHET` в принципе очень простая библиотека для создания простого ***ЧАТА***. Именно чата, не ЛС. Тупо нигде в сети я не нашёл как сделать ЛС, диалоги и тп. на этой библиотеке и вообще на php. Везде либо ЛС php-mySql, либо чат ratchet-php.

### Как отправлять сообщения только конкретным пользователям

Система как сделать такой чат в принципе понятна. Нужно сделать таблицу с диалогами и таблицу с сообщениями.

1. В таблице с диалогами будет айди диалога, айди продовца, айди
   покупателя, айди товара
2. В таблице с сообщениями будет айди сообщения, айди диалога, к которому относится сообщение, роль отправителя и сообщение

Потом нужно при нажатии на кнопку "написать продавцу" Нужно создать новое соединение с вебсокетом и в onopen нужно создать соотношение `пользователь-айди диалога`, а потом отправлять сообщения только тем, у кого совпадает айди диалога с айди диалога отправителя, тому отправлять сообщение, а остальным нет. Но как это реализовать, я не знаю.

---

Сейчас у меня код с документации Ratchet

```html
<?php namespace ColorCore;

// file ChatRoom.php //

require 'W:\domains\colorShop\vendor\autoload.php';

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class SocketChat implements MessageComponentInterface {
  protected $clients;
  protected $rooms;

  public function __construct() {
      $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
      $this->rooms = new \SplObjectStorage;
  }

  public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
      // Store the new connection to send messages to later
      $this->clients->attach($conn);

      $chat = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM chats WHERE seller = '$seller' AND 
                                                      buyer = '$buyer' AND 
                                                      good = '$goodId'");
      $chat = $chat->fetch_assoc();

      $this->rooms->attach($conn);

      echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
  }

  public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    $msg = json_encode($msg);

    $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
    echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
        , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

    foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
      // if ($from !== $client) {
          // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
          $client->send($msg);
          // $client->send($msg);
      // }
    }

  }

  public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
      // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
      $this->clients->detach($conn);

      echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
  }

  public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
      echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

      $conn->close();
  }
}
```

```js
window.conn = new WebSocket(websocketPath);

// send only if connected
let wsSend = function(data) {
  if (!conn.readyState) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      wsSend(data);
    }, 100);
  } else {
    conn.send(data);
  }
};
// if connection is established
conn.onopen = function(e) {
  console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onclose = function(e) {
  console.log("Connection is closed");
};
conn.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log("ERROR:" + e.message);
};

// if a message arrived
conn.onmessage = function(e) {
  let data = JSON.parse(e.data);
  console.log(data);
};
```

```html
<?php 

//file WSchat.php

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use ColorCore\SocketChat;

require  'vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new SocketChat()
        )
    ),
    8777
);

$server->run();
```

Могу перейти на другую библиотеку. Лишь бы сделать этот чат. Мучаюсь очень долго.
Задавал уже подобный вопрос, но его забраковали (-3). Править его уже нет смысла)

Comment: Почему -1? Напишите причину исправлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наконец, я нашёл как сделать этот чат!

https://medium.com/@errohitdhiman/real-time-one-to-one-and-group-chat-with-php-laravel-ratchet-websocket-library-javascript-and-c64ba20621ed

### **НЕБОЛЬШОЙ ПРИМЕР**

Оказывается у объекта `$conn` есть своё айди - resourceId.
В примере есть команда register:
По ней из js отправляем `userId`, а на сервере выполняется такая команда

```
$this->userresources[$data->userId][] = $conn->resourceId;
```

Например, мы отправили `command: "register", userId: 21` -- в массив users под индексом 21(От айди, которое мы отправили) записалось текущее подключение юзера.

Теперь можно через команду message ( `command: "message", to: "21", message: "from me only to you` ) отправить сообщение только тому, у кого userId = 21

На сервере берётся подключение из массива `users` и с индексом `21` и отправляется сообщение

```
$this->users[$resourceId]->send($msg);
```

### **P.s**

Искренне надеюсь, что я помог всееем, кто пытается сделать такой чат!
Итак, я долго и упорно искал инфу в интернете, но везде рассказывалось про групповой чат - отправляешь сообщение, и оно разлетается всем.

В примере использовался ratchet